# Table attribute meanings in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

For a project using beautifulsoup I need to acquire the "Tesla Quarterly Revenue" table from this site,  https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue. I think ive acquired the initial html data accurately but I'm unsure what tag the phrase "Tesla Quarterly Revenue" is attached  to, I thought it might be under thead but that does not output the table.

```
r=requests.get( 'https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue')
html_data=r.text
soup=BeautifulSoup(html_data)
#print(soup.prettify())
table_=soup.find_all('thead','Tesla Quarterly Revenue')
table_row=table_.find_all('tr')
for row in table_row:
    col = row.find_all("td")
    date =col[0].text
    revenue =col[1].text
    tesla_revenue = tesla_revenue.append({"Date":date, "Revenue":revenue}, ignore_index=True)

tesla_revenue.head()
```

Soup output here

```
 <div class="col-xs-6">
       <table class="historical_data_table table">
        <thead>
         <tr>
          <th colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
           Tesla Quarterly Revenue
           <br/>
           <span style="font-size:14px;">
            (Millions of US $)
           </span>
          </th>
         </tr>
        </thead>
```

I know i could select the whole area using

```
soup.find_all('div',class_='col-xs-6')
```

But there are multiple tables under this tag and im unsure how to refine it further. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I've figured I can grab the table this way, table_=soup.find_all('table')
table_=table_[1] , but that requires inspecting at multiple points to get the table number (and knowing it exists)

Answer (score 1):

It is in a table header. You can grab with the following css selector

```
soup.select_one('#style-1 div + div .historical_data_table th')
```

If you want literally the first line only, you can use stripped_strings and index 0:

```
[s for s in soup.select_one('#style-1 div + div .historical_data_table th').stripped_strings][0]
```

As there are multiple tables with the class `historical_data_table`, the above selector uses element with id `style-1` as an anchor, the moves to the table with class `historical_data_table` that is a child of a `div` which is an immediate sibling of another `div`, which is a child of that anchor; it then moves to the child `th` of that table.

Answer (score 1):

You should first select `main_content div` then select table inside it and finally find the right table.
this code will help you to find the right tbody:

```
r=requests.get( 'https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/revenue')
html_data=r.text
soup=BeautifulSoup(html_data)
main = soup.find('div',id = 'main_content')
tables = main.find_all('table', class_='historical_data_table table')
table_ = ''
for table in tables:
    if table.text.find('Tesla Quarterly Revenue') >= 0:
        table_ = table
        break
table_ = table_.find('tbody')

table_row=table_.find_all('tr')
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to be what I'm after! Why do you create the empty table_ object before the for loop, is it to prevent an error if there is no table found?